# new to iOS determine which scene comes first

Tags: ios, objective-c

this might seem like a very basic question but I am new to iOS.
I am building upon an existing game project. When you run the app, the main scene appears for you to play. But I need to have a different scene(user screen) appear before the main scene. Then they can press a button and that will take them to the main scene.

I looked through some documentation yet I could not find how to do this.

Comment: Are you using a storyboard or xibs?

Comment: i am using storyboard

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done either done in the storyboard or in `-[UIApplicationDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:]` method.

At any point you can change the "main scene" by setting `window.rootViewController`.

You said you are working with a game. Do you know what framework you are working with? This might change the answer.

Comment: can you give me some more detail? this is like, really broad. I am not using a framework because this is a very simple game.

Comment: i nice tutorial would be great too if u can find one

Answer (score 0):

I think this tutorial will be very useful to you:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Quote from this tutorial about how to set the initial view controller in the storyboard: "Select the Tab Bar Controller and go to the Attributes Inspector. Check the box that says Is Initial View Controller."

Comment: P.S. In general, you should really read up on your own a bit more before coming back here to post questions because people here may not be so happy when you post questions about something you could have easily figured out on your own…and all those down votes you're getting hurts your "reputation" on this site.  The people here will be more receptive if it feels like you're putting in some effort.  Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is another option to do this is, go to .storyboard file and change **Is initial view controller** property to Yes for view controller which you want to display first.